# Unable to get data from aws sns email bounce notification message

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have subscribed my endpoint and now I need to pull the emailAddress from the object/array I cannot get the value 'fakeemail@
    gmail.com' for the life of me

```
Aws\Sns\Message Object
(
data:Aws\Sns\Message:private => Array
(
Type => Notification
MessageId => hghkvvhhv32hg32vh23v32hjk32bjk
TopicArn => arn:aws:sns:us-west-232jh32bhj322j3hv23jhv23jhv2
Message => {"notificationType":"Bounce","bounce":{"bounceType":"Permanent","bounceSubType":"Suppressed","bouncedRecipients":,"timestamp":"2016-06-21T04:43:05.786Z","feedbackId":"wef-a5166c3e-fe-11e6-923e4-1115qbdde1aq2907d-000000","reportingMTA":"dns; amazonses.com"},"mail":{"timestamp":"2016-06-21T04:43:04.000Z","source":"www-data@myserver.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:0f2243234320627162:identity/myserver.com","sendingAccountId":"0243122452162","messageId":"0103714433d74e-e3bfd2dd3b3b7-49238-45a3f-953fa-c9a3eb3fd312c-03300000","destination":["fakeemail@
gmail.com"]}}
Timestamp => 2016-06-21T04:43:05.882Z
SignatureVersion => 1
Signature => vfvdfvsdffsvfadvfdvdfvdfdfsdvsdfdf
SigningCertURL => https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-vafvadfvadsvdsfdsvsvdsdfsdvsdsvd.pem
UnsubscribeURL => https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:02vsddfvddv43230vfvsvf67162:email_bounce:5fc6vsdfvd6af9-cfssdvdv197-4vfsdf0f-afb7-67fvdfs1b
)
)
```

I have changed my details above but this is what is given. I need to get the 
fakeemail@gmail.com from array in the object but cant for the life of me

//from aws sdk

```
$message = Message::fromRawPostData();
```

I used

```
print_r($message['Message'], true);
```

to get the data above  would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. You want to take the

```
$message['Message']
```

and encode it to json to use as an object

```
$test = json_decode($message['Message']);
$returnsMyAnswer = print_r($test-> mail-> destination[0], true);
```

and then

```
echo $returnsMyAnswer;
```

and you get

```
fakeemail@ gmail.com
```

Comment: "Decode it from JSON," not "encode it as JSON."  It's already JSON.  Also, don't test with fake addresses.  SES frowns upon sending messages to actual bogus email addresses, since it suggests to them that you could be a spammer with a sloppily-maintained list.  Use `bounce@simulator.amazonses.com`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html. Good coding style suggests that you never assume an array has only one member.  Iterate them all even if you only expect 1 to be present, or you could be discarding useful data, setting yourself up for bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I wonder why the decode worked?? From what I have seen I only get 1 email address per bounce as I also have a sns email notification for the same subscription.

Comment: Your code wasn't the issue -- your description was.  My comment makes the point that you **said** **"encode** it to json to use as an object when you intended to say "decode it from json to use as an object."  And, yes, I realize that "often" there's only one recipient, but when a structure, like this, permits more than one, you need to expect that there may be more than one.  In fact, I have cases in my records where a message was sent to two people, one of which had an out-of-office alert, and both appeared in the bounce.

Comment: Actually, that's wrong, in fact... heads-up: you seem to be looking at the wrong field. The `destination` is documented as the list of all recipients.  You actually need to be looking at `bounce->bouncedRecipients[0]->emailAddress` (and not just element 0 of course).  In the example I just mentioned, both receipients appear in `destination` but only one of them (the one that actually bounced) was in `bouncedRecipients`.  You omitted part of the JSON from your original post.

Comment: I will have to check that out for sure, thank you Michael-sqlbot